# I can't authenticate at gmail via python

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, gmail

I'm trying to send an email via gmail:

```
  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg["From"] = "to@fdsfds.com"
  msg["To"] = ", ".join(recipients_array)
  msg["Subject"] = subject
  msg.attach(MIMEText(msg_body))


  # server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
  server.ehlo()
  server.starttls()
  server.ehlo()
  server.login(my_gmail_address, my_gmail_password) # error here

  server.sendmail(my_gmail_address, recipients, msg.as_string())
  server.close()
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    # .......
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuZg\n5.7.14 fsfdsfds-kK\n5.7.14 fdsfdsfds-CyIaJn4-TUONIr_gHn9\n5.7.14 gfdgfd-543543\n5.7.14 aaaa> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 d8sm43303847pas.14 - gsmtp')
```

I'm authenticated in a browser at gmail.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) you might need to change your security settings to enable access for less secure apps.

Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps to turn on access to less secure apps.

If that doesn't fix the problem, you should read the information referenced in the traceback's error message: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Comment: @OskarK.: did you go through all of the "Troubleshoot sign-in problems" listed here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 ? e.g. do you have 2 factor authentication enabled on your account?

Comment: what could I possible mean by "nothing has helped"?

Comment: Literally, that you have done nothing... and that has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely an issue with authentication like mhawke suggested.

For a list of common errors as well as a much more convenient library, have a look at [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).

Syntax would look like:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(username, password)
yag.send("toaddr@gmail.com", "this subject", "text content")
```

Full disclosure: I developed yagmail.

Comment: how is it more convinient?

Comment: Look at the provided link, a whole readme devoted to it. Simply put: you will need a lot less code.